# Is white space relevant when casting from the 'any' type in Apama EPL?

Tags: apama

I am on Apama 10.3 (Community Edition):

```
any emptyString := "";
any emptyDictionary := new dictionary<string,any>;
string myString := <string> emptyString;
dictionary<string,any> := <dictionary<string,any>> emptyDictionary;
```

The cast in line 3 works, but in line 4 Designer complains about unexpected token: `<`. Only if I use white spaces does it work:

```
dictionary<string,any> := <dictionary< string,any> > emptyDictionary;
```

In the documentation [Developing Apama Applications](http://www.apamacommunity.com/documents/10.3.0.2/apama_10.3.0.2_webhelp/apama-webhelp/#page/apama-webhelp%2Fto-help_developing_apama_applications.html%23) this is not mentioned but on page 296 when casting with `optional<>`, the correct syntax with the white spaces is used.

Does this work as expected or is it a bug?

Comment: As Henry explained, the space in between `<` and `string` in `< string` holds no relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here isn't about casting to an `any` type.  This is due to the EPL parser always interpreting expression `>>` as a right-shift operator.  If you need to close two angle brackets, you always need to use a space between them.  It’s only the closing brackets that are affected (as you’d never need to write `<<` in EPL).

The form I always use is:

```
dictionary<string,any> x := <dictionary<string,any> > emptyDictionary;
sequence<sequence<string> > jaggedArray := new sequence<sequence<string> >;
```